# setText() method not working for TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to set text with certain name . my code is as follows. i am setting text to test but its not reflecting.

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page4, null);
         score = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.galcount);
         score.setText("TEST");
}
```

my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/darkblack">


    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/galcount"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="gallery">
    </TextView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is this __android:textColor="#ffffe4ef"__? :-)

Comment: It is almost white color.

Comment: You need to have 6 alphabets only

Comment: i changed it to #ffffff stil not reflecting.

Comment: Does "gallery" show up?

Comment: ya gallery is working fine. i just want to show image name above gallery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86670/discussion-between-spiderman-and-namratha).

Comment: You don't even return an Object in your method. Should not compile

Answer (score 1):

You have many errors in your code:

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page4, container, false);
    score = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.galcount);
    score.setText("TEXT");
    return view;
}
```

You may not inflate a view with a null on the root place, specially if you've provided the container `ViewGroup`.

You have to return the view, if you don't do it your program won't compile, and also the caller of the function won't receive the view and I'm sure that you don't want it.

Be sure that your `inflater` is declared with the correct `context`, because if it's not the correct one the view will not be shown or even worse, your program will crash in some cases.

Comment: Still my text is not replacing with name "TEXT"

Comment: You are setting `"TEST"` in your code. I've edited mine with `"TEXT"` now

Comment: I mean it is still showing gallery only. It is not replacing the text

Comment: Check the context, I'm sure that the error is there.